# How do I stop getting errors when importing cdns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cdn

This is my code. Why do I get these errors? Have been trying a thousand ways and keep getting nowhere.

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/Observer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@<version>/build/three.module.js",
          "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@<version>/examples/jsm/",
            "gsap": "https://unpkg.com/browse/gsap@<version>/src/gsap-core.js",
            "gsap/": "https://unpkg.com/browse/gsap@<version>/src/",
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
```

```js
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { EffectComposer } from "three/addons/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js";
import { RenderPass } from "three/addons/postprocessing/RenderPass.js";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { Observer } from "gsap/Observer";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import { ScrollToPlugin } from "gsap/ScrollToPlugin"
import state from "https://gramophone-frezy.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bestR.json";
import * as core from '@theatre/core.js'
```

GET https://unpkg.com/three@%3Cversion%3E/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.js:3          GET https://unpkg.com/three@%3Cversion%3E/build/three.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.js:10          GET https://unpkg.com/browse/gsap@%3Cversion%3E/src/ScrollToPlugin net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.js:6          GET https://unpkg.com/three@%3Cversion%3E/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.js:7          GET https://unpkg.com/browse/gsap@%3Cversion%3E/src/gsap-core.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.js:5          GET https://unpkg.com/three@%3Cversion%3E/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.js:12          GET https://unpkg.com/browse/theatre@%3Cversion%3E/core.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.js:9          GET https://unpkg.com/browse/gsap@%3Cversion%3E/src/ScrollTrigger net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.js:8          GET https://unpkg.com/browse/gsap@%3Cversion%3E/src/Observer net::ERR_ABORTED 404

I also get these errors

sound.png:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/png". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
sound2.png:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/png". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
bestR.json:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

When I import them as

```js
import soundImg from 'https://gramophone-frezy.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sound.png';
import soundImg2 from 'https://gramophone-frezy.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/sound2.png';
```

and

```js
import soundImg from './images/sound.png';
import soundImg2 from './images/sound2.png';
import state from "./scene/bestR.json";
```

I would very much appreciate the help as I am completely out of ideas.
To add some context, I am trying to upload the website to Hostinger from a Vite project. Hosting locally worked without the cdns, but didn't on hostinger so I tried with cdns and got this far.

Answer (score 0):

Your [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/) URLs contain the text "@<version>" - perhaps because you just copied the pattern from somewhere. However, "<version>" is meant to be replaced by an actual version number (such as `1.2.3` or similar).

In many cases, you may also simply omit the "@<version>" and then automatically retrieve the latest version of a package.